# Как сбросить состояние UI в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть вопроса:
Есть меню в игре. Пользователь выбирает некие настройки и при нажатии кнопки "Начать" загружается новая сцена. В Canvas и EventSystem прописано DontDestroyOnLoad. Соответственно UI при загрузке сцены работает, но меню остается в том же положении, в котором было до загрузки сцены, некоторых кнопок не видно, некоторые наоборот показывается, хотя не должны. Состояние кнопок (что скрываем, что показываем) прописано в отдельном классе в Awake. Можно ли как-то "триггернуть" интерфейс, чтобы сработал метод Awake из класса, в котором прописано, что скрывается, что показывается?

Comment: Сделайте публичный метод, например Reset(), перенесите в него код из Awake, вызыввйте его и из Awake и когда захотите сбросить состояние. Это должно быть просто.

Comment: Пробовала, все то же самое, лишь некоторые кнопки исчезают. Этот метод отдельно куда-то вынести или оставить в том же классе, где прописан весь интерфейс? И где правильнее вызывать его, до загрузки сцены в onClick (сцена загружается кликом по кнопке) или после? Перед/после DontDestroyOnLoad в GameObject'ах, которые не нужно удалять? Или в каком-то пустом объекте на новой сцене?

Comment: Найдите сначало место, где оно будет оаботать, а уж потом ищите, где лучше.

Comment: @aepot я имею в виду не как лучше, а как надо) доберусь до компа посмотрю куда я там этот метод впихнула и отпишусь, что не так

Comment: Вопрос задан про сферический код в вакууме, который видите только вы, что здесь можно ещё ответить?

Comment: @aepot DontDestroy у меня прописан в Canvas, Event System и в пустом объекте, на котором висит скрипт, управляющий интерфейсом. DontDestroy отдельным скриптом. Для отображения меню есть булевая переменная. Метод Reset тоже есть. При нажатии на кнопку загружается новая сцена. В инспекторе при этом булевая переменная равна false, что как бы намекает, что интерфейс все таки скрывается. Но его почему-то видно

Comment: @eapot все работает относительно корректно, но: когда нажимаю кнопку, которая переносит на другую сцену, все зависает (UI, задник исходной сцены). нет, это не загрузка, т.к. при нажатии на кнопку, которая открывает/скрывает меню, оно скрывается как и должно и в этот момент только появляется вторая сцена. Как я поняла DontDestroy не вызывает Awake()